# Before / After steps not called in Item processors of ClassifierCompositeItemProcessor

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-batch, batch-processing

Here is the sample code block (I remove our stuff and kept only the skeleton code)

```
public class ItemProcessor1 implements ItemProcessor{

    private StepExecution stepExecution;
        
    @BeforeStep **// Not called.**
    public void beforeStep(final StepExecution stepExecution) {
        this.stepExecution = stepExecution;
    }

    @AfterStep  **// Not called.**
    public ExitStatus afterStep() {
       return ExitStatus.COMPLETED;
    }

    @Override
    public Record process(Record rec) throws Exception {
        return super.process(rec);
    }
}

public class ItemProcessor2 implements ItemProcessor{

    private StepExecution stepExecution;
        
    @BeforeStep  **// Not called**.
    public void beforeStep(final StepExecution stepExecution) {
        this.stepExecution = stepExecution;
    }

    @AfterStep  **// Not called.**
    public ExitStatus afterStep() {
        return ExitStatus.COMPLETED;
    }

    @Override
    public Record process(Record rec) throws Exception {
        return super.process(rec);
    }
}

@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class ItemProcessorRecordClassifier
                            implements Classifier {

    private final ItemProcessor1 itemProcessor1;
    private final ItemProcessor2 itemProcessor2;
    public ItemProcessor classify(Record record) {
        return (record.getRowNum()%2==0) ? itemProcessor1 : itemProcessor2
    }

}

public class RecordClassifierCompositeItemProcessor extends ClassifierCompositeItemProcessor {

    private StepExecution stepExecution;
        
    @BeforeStep  // Called.
    public void beforeStep(final StepExecution stepExecution) {
        this.stepExecution = stepExecution;
    }

    @AfterStep  // Called.
    public ExitStatus afterStep() {
        return ExitStatus.COMPLETED;
    }

    @Override
    public Record process(Record rec) throws Exception {
        return super.process(rec);
    }
}

//Config

@Bean
// @StepScope
public ItemProcessor1 itemProcessor1() {
    return new ItemProcessor1();
}

@Bean
// @StepScope
public ItemProcessor2 itemProcessor2() {
    return new ItemProcessor2();
}

@Bean
public ItemProcessorRecordClassifier itemProcessorRecordClassifier(
    final ItemProcessor1 itemProcessor1,
    final ItemProcessor2 itemProcessor2) {
    return new ItemProcessorRecordClassifier(itemProcessor1, itemProcessor2);
}

@Bean
@StepScope
public RecordClassifierCompositeItemProcessor processor(final ItemProcessorRecordClassifier itemProcessorRecordClassifier) {
    RecordClassifierCompositeItemProcessor compositeProcessor = new RecordClassifierCompositeItemProcessor();
        compositeProcessor.setClassifier(itemProcessorRecordClassifier);
        return compositeProcessor;
}
```

I was expecting to do some before / after processing in each of the item processors specific to the record... But, Spring batch isn't calling the item processor's before / after step. I also tried with 'StepScope' for the two item processors to no avail. Is it normal for spring batch to not called the before/after step of item processors of classifier composite ones?

Comment: You shoud use an ItemProcessorListener so you can create a class that implement the interface ItemProcessorListener  and after you can define your implementation ( beforeProcess & afterProcess ). But in you code i see that you want to use beforeStep & AfterStep in the class of your processor.

Comment: I couldn't spring batch call the other 'processors' before/after step. The above composite one it calls only the main processors and not the sub ones... So I re-wrote using single processor and delegated some of the work to other utility/processor helpers for now. Thanks for your response!

Answer (score 1):

This is because you are using a composite processor. You can only register one item processor in a step. As you can see, those methods were called for the composite.

So you either need to make your composite call those methods for the delegate processors, or manually register the delegate processors as listeners in the step.

Comment: Thanks Ben! I am actually looking for the step execution here and hence was hoping my before / after step to be called... before / after process method of item processor I do not see them getting step execution input... But, I will provision time to check that later...